# Serving static files in django with Nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Hi guys im trying to run my project on nginx with gunicorn. I can successfully access it but i have a problem on serving static files. I totally understand how manage.py collect static works but i think i am missing something on my configuration file in nginx or in my settings.py. Hope you can help me.

[image]

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    #server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /root/Desktop/halcyon---recruitment-system/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

My project static path is: /root/Desktop/halcyon---recruitment-system/staticfiles/

Comment: can you share your nginx config and also state what problem you are specifically facing?

Comment: @Bernard'BetaBerlin'Parah edited my post. my problem is that my static files is not being read when i run it with gunicorn.

Comment: According to your directory try this in nginx         `alias   /root/Desktop/halcyon---recruitment-system/files/;`

Comment: alias /root/Desktop/halcyon---recruitment-system/files/. i tried replacing my alias with this path but it still doesnt work. why alias /root/Desktop/halcyon---recruitment-system/files/;? because this directory contains other static files i needed for my project so im a bit confused why did you come with that conclusion.

Comment: UPDATE: when i go to the static directory. I get 403 forbidden. i think im having file permission issue